# How to ORDER columns in csv once the grouped in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to order the columns once they are already grouped.  How can I do this?
My data looks like this:

```
product,next_link,count_value
p1,p2,2
p1,p4,4
p1,p5,5
p2,p1,3
p2,p3,2
p3,p2,1
p3,p5,6
p3,p1,8
p4,p1,8
p4,p5,2
p5,p3,3
p5,p2,5
p5,p4,6
p5,p1,4
```

I grouped them using this piece of code:

```
product_group = GROUP product_data BY products;
DUMP product_group;
```

The output is:

```
(p1,{(p1,p2,2),(p1,p4,4),(p1,p5,5)})
(p2,{(p2,p1,3),(p2,p3,2)})
(p3,{(p3,p5,6),(p3,p1,8),(p3,p2,1)})
(p4,{(p4,p5,2),(p4,p1,8)})
(p5,{(p5,p1,4),(p5,p3,3),(p5,p2,5),(p5,p4,6)})
```

I want to use `ORDER` to order the next_link base on `count_value`.
I have written the code as:

```
B = FOREACH product_data {
    field2_ord = ORDER next_link BY count_value;
    GENERATE products, field2_ord;
    };
```

Comment: I believe your code should work. Whats the expected output and what output are you getting from above code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the product data in order of count_value then you can use:

```
A = LOAD 'Product_data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (product:chararray, next_link:chararray, count_value:int);
B = ORDER A BY count_value ASC;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE product, next_link;
DUMP C;
```

I hope this is what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
a_input = LOAD 'Product_data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (product:chararray, next_link:chararray, count_value:int);
B = GROUP (ORDER a_input BY count_value) BY next_link;
```

Are you expecting this type of code?